# Column not found in the data.table when using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, r-markdown

I was wondering why the Species column could not be found in the following code:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("s", label = "Species:",
              choices = unique(iris$Species))
)

renderPlot({
  iris.dt <- data.table(iris)
  ggplot(iris.dt[Species == input$s], aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
})
````

How should it be written?

**EDIT:**

```
Output created: C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0Af32S/file243c5299469.html
Warning: Error in [.data.frame: object 'Species' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    105: [.data.frame
    104: [.data.table
    103: [
    102: ggplot
    101: renderPlot [<text>#8]
     91: <reactive:plotObj>
     80: plotObj
     79: origRenderFunc
     78: output$out6967b1458d9fe4b5
      3: <Anonymous>
      2: do.call
      1: rmarkdown::run
```

I use Windows 7, Shiny 1.0.3, Rmarkdown 1.5, data.table 1.10.4, R 3.4.0, ggplot 2.2.1.

I also found this: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1696

Comment: Works fine on my setup : win_7, R_3.3.2, shiny_1.0.0, data.table_1.10.4, ggplot2_2.2.1

Comment: If I run the Rmarkdown document, I get Error: object 'Species' not found.

Comment: I have no problem too. Looks like data.table is not loaded.